# Trying to make a paintbrush effect for my drawing app, but it starts too thick

Tags: processing

As part of my course I have been tasked with creating a drawing app in Processing with the goal of it running on my nexus. However when this code runs the paintbrush effect looks great for the first line, but the weight of the line does not reset correctly so the next line always starts too thick, any help would be much appreciated.

Here is what i have so far

```java
float max = 6;
float thickness = 1;
void setup()
{ 
 size(500, 500);
 smooth();
background(255); 
}
void draw() 
{ 
 if(mousePressed) 
{ 
  if(thickness < max) 
    { 
    line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX,pmouseY); 
    strokeWeight(thickness); 
    thickness = thickness+0.25; 
    }
   else 
   { 
     line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX,pmouseY);
     strokeWeight(max);
   }
} 
}
void mouseReleased() 
{ 
thickness = thickness/thickness; 
}
```

Comment: It is written in processing witch is a java subdivision; sorry if that was not clear

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Is it relevant to add the java tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the program executes from top to bottom, you need to call `strokeWeight(thickness);` before `line()`, so it will draw the line with proper `thickness`. Just change this order and you are good.

```java
float max = 6;
float thickness = 1;
void setup()
{ 
  size(500, 500);
  smooth();
  background(255);
}
void draw() 
{ 
  if (mousePressed) 
  { 
    if (thickness < max) 
    { 
      strokeWeight(thickness); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< THIS! :)
      line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY); 
      thickness = thickness+0.25;
    }
    else 
    { 
      line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
      strokeWeight(max);
    }
  }
}
void mouseReleased() 
{ 
  thickness = thickness/thickness;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch man; this has saves me a bunch of time